# Nodejs: get filename of caller function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wonder how-to get an absolute path of a caller of a function?

Let say that:

in file `a.js` I call `b()`; `b()` is a function defined in file `b.js`. `a.js`requires `b` . So how do I get `a.js` absolute path from `b.js` in node?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227489/how-can-one-get-the-file-path-of-the-caller-function-in-node-js

Comment: And see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111163/in-node-js-how-can-i-get-the-path-of-a-module-i-have-loaded-via-require-that-is

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872310/52499).

Comment: `console.log((new Error()).stack.split("\n")[1].split("/").slice(-1)[0].split(":")[0]) // "caller_file_name.js"`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is an example how to use stacktrace to find caller file in node

```js
function _getCallerFile() {
    var filename;

    var _pst = Error.prepareStackTrace
    Error.prepareStackTrace = function (err, stack) { return stack; };
    try {
        var err = new Error();
        var callerfile;
        var currentfile;

        currentfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

        while (err.stack.length) {
            callerfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

            if(currentfile !== callerfile) {
                filename = callerfile;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {}
    Error.prepareStackTrace = _pst;

    return filename;
}
```

Comment: IMPORTANT! Scroll down a bit and there are updated answers that don't have the same potential bugs and pitfalls as this one (though I did edit it to omit the most egregious bug). @Christoph's seems to be the best.

Comment: This fails when using a bundler.

Comment: @brillout you at least need to mention which one

Answer (score 52):

Failing to restore the prepareStackTrace function can cause issues. Here's an example that removes side-effects

```
function _getCallerFile() {
    var originalFunc = Error.prepareStackTrace;

    var callerfile;
    try {
        var err = new Error();
        var currentfile;

        Error.prepareStackTrace = function (err, stack) { return stack; };

        currentfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

        while (err.stack.length) {
            callerfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

            if(currentfile !== callerfile) break;
        }
    } catch (e) {}

    Error.prepareStackTrace = originalFunc; 

    return callerfile;
}
```

Comment: Great! I was trying to solve an issue related to that for hours. Reassigning the original function fixed everything.

Comment: hi, this solution works fine... but if a function was called in a callback then it will get the name of the file that fired the callback

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use `finally` for resetting `Error.prepareStackTrace`?

Comment: This fails when using a bundler + mostly duplicate of older answer.

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly answering the question here
but some might appreciate this information.

With NodeJS & Forever(-monitor),
the following contains a filename from which the process was started:

```
process.mainModule.filename
```

Haven't tried many uses™ though.

This seems to be a pretty decent explanation: https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi.

Comment: Definitely doesn't answer the question but this helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In case the function you need the caller file of is not called in the file where it is implemented – as is the case in the OP's scenario – you can just write:

```js
function _getCallerFile()
{
    const prepareStackTraceOrg = Error.prepareStackTrace;
    const err = new Error();

    Error.prepareStackTrace = (_, stack) => stack;

    const stack = err.stack;

    Error.prepareStackTrace = prepareStackTraceOrg;

    return stack[1].getFileName();
}
```

The `try...catch` is unnecessary since the `Error` will not be thrown if you assign it to a variable.

Furthermore, you might want to put `_getCallerFile` in its own file if you want to use it in multiple projects, but then, you will get the name of the file where `_getCallerFile` has been called.
In this case, just write `return stack[2].getFileName();`, i. e. go one more step back in the call stack.

If you are using TypeScript, you must write `const stack = err.stack as unknown as NodeJS.CallSite[];` because `Error.stack`'s declared type is `string`, but our `prepareStackTrace` function returns an array of `NodeJS.CallSite` objects.

And just FYI: `NodeJS.CallSite` has further interesting methods, e. g. `getFunctionName`.

**Update**

I noticed that `Error.prepareStackTrace === undefined` before assigning the lambda. If you don't trust me, just add `console.log('prepareStackTraceOrg:', prepareStackTraceOrg);` to the function.
Thus, we can simplify the function:

```js
function _getCallerFile()
{
    const err = new Error();

    Error.prepareStackTrace = (_, stack) => stack;

    const stack = err.stack;

    Error.prepareStackTrace = undefined;

    return stack[1].getFileName();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use https://github.com/sindresorhus/callsites

If you use the first answer you could mess up with other libraries trying to do the same thing. See for example: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5303

Answer (score 3):

The npm [caller package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/caller) has a function that returns the path and filename of the callers.

Comment: The caller package returns internal/module.js when debugging.

Comment: The posted example on github also returns the same "internal/module.js" as caller on node v8.11.1

Answer (score 1):

Getting a stacktrace in JavaScript is quite hard. The best method I've found is to throw an Error, catch it, get the stack from `Error.getStack()` (not implemented in all browsers, that means you IE.) and formatting the output.

Each stack frame gives you a filepath, line number and function name. Webkit even has support for arguments but that wasn't working yet when I last checked.

Then there is the problem of tracing code across different events.

I actually wrote a blog post about this: http://fritsvancampen.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/error-handling-in-javascript-a-better-way/

Comment: try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
does not work on nodejs

Comment: You can't JSON encode native objects. Why would you even want to do that? :S

Answer (score -1):

You can use `require.resolve(module)` to determine the full path of a module:

```
var path = require.resolve("a");

//or

var path = require.resolve("./a.js");
```

Comment: the caller is not always pre-determined, so: this way will not work

Comment: Resolve is used for merging paths, or traversing paths. To find the patch of a caller is different.