# Is there a way to know from which file a function is called in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a module for a logger and I want it to add a prefix each time the function `dlog()` is being called with the filename of the file calling the function. Right now I have to call it each time like this:

```
dlog(__filename + " log text");
```

Is there a way to detect the name of the file calling the function without this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Nodejs: get filename of caller function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697791/nodejs-get-filename-of-caller-function) :

`function _getCallerFile() {
    try {
        var err = new Error();
        var callerfile;
        var currentfile;`

```
    Error.prepareStackTrace = function (err, stack) { return stack; };

    currentfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

    while (err.stack.length) {
        callerfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

        if(currentfile !== callerfile) return callerfile;
    }
} catch (err) {}
return undefined;
```

}