# How to get current path of the file that run the script in nodejs

Tags: node.js, path

So I have node modules that can be require for Internationalization.

I'm trying to get the current path of the file that run my node module inside the nodule module.

Use case #1:

Inside `~/yourProject/node_modules/i18n.js`

```
var current_path_to_locales_dir = path.join(__dirname, "locale");
```

And the path of the server is:

```
~/YourUserName/yourProject/app.js
```

Doing `var i18n = require("i18n");`

And trying to get the path it will return

```
/User/YourUserName/yourProject/node_modules/locale
```

Which is correct but I'm expecting it to look for

```
/User/YourUserName/yourProject/locale
```

Use case #2:

Inside `~/i18nProject/i18n.js`

```
var current_path_to_locales_dir = path.join(__dirname, "locale");
```

If I have a sample app in the `~/i18nProject/sample` and doing `var i18n = require("../i18n");`

The `locale` directory this time will be

```
/User/YourUserName/i18nProject/locale
```

Again the above is correct but I would expect it to be

```
/User/i18nProject/sample/locale/
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a way that I can get the path of the current running script?

Comment: try `process.cwd()`, is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: @vmx `process.cwd()` would return the path to the place where you run the file?

Comment: it returns the current working directory. If left untouched, that is the directory you ran `node app` or the like in, but users can use `process.chdir` and change it. If you tie into it before users change the working dir, you're good, but it's not guaranteed correct.

Answer (score 20):

Use the variables __filename, __dirname will return called modules/scripts name and path, see here http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename

### Update

In your case you need to get the caller of module/script:

Node.js does not do it for you, so technically you may have to add extra wrapper and parameter to your module and convert it into a function that accepts this information.

However, there is a work around to implement getCaller by using Error.prepareStackTrace
This thread already has your solution:

[How can one get the file path of the caller function in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227489/how-can-one-get-the-file-path-of-the-caller-function-in-node-js)

Comment: `console.log(__filename);` will return the path to the file not the path of the file that ran the script.

Answer (score 3):

### Case 1:

If you want a default `locals` directory in the project of the user consuming your npm package, change this line:

```
var current_path_to_locales_dir = path.join(__dirname, "locale");
```

to:

```
var current_path_to_locales_dir = path.join(__dirname, "..", "locale");
// The ".." moves back one directory out of node_modules.
```

Just be sure that the file running the above code is in the root of your npm package. It might be better to change to `path.resolve` but I'll let you explore the differences as this is out of the scope of your question.

### Case 2:

If you want to access a sample directory in your npm package by using `require("../i18n");`, change this line:

```
var current_path_to_locales_dir = path.join(__dirname, "locale");
```

to:

```
var current_path_to_locales_dir = path.join(__dirname, "sample", "locale");
```

Same as case 1, make sure the file running above code is in the root of your npm package

Comment: Well that is a bit like we are hardcoding the path no? like I don't really know when is the case they will use either one of the two.

Comment: Sorry, I inferred from you code that you were intending to force a directory structure on the consumer of your npm package.

Comment: Yeah, not really like that unfortunately is not going to be known about the use case but I'm just giving some possible use case here :(

Comment: Setting directory locations through a configuration object is probably going to be your best bet

Comment: which is what I have for the user right now. I thought it might be a way to do so if not I guess I have to go back to the old fashion way. Provide us the `dir` :P

Comment: Classic battle of Convention vs. Configuration. My answer will set a convention, but for maximum flexibility, you'll want to use configuration =)