# How to create function (inside module) that consume relative path of file in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

What I am trying to do is creating function like NodeJS `require`. You can do `require("./your-file")` and `require` understand that the file `./your-file` is sibling of the calling module, without specifying the full path of the file.

My current problem is getting the directory of current executing function (`__dirname` of the executing function)

I tried things below:

- Using `module.parent.fileName` failed when the calling method wrapped with other function.
- [By reading from V8 stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19788257/212706) almost there but failed when run inside test runner (Jest)

It should be an easy solution for this, maybe I'm over complicate it?

Comment: Actually this is quite complicated, see https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L354 (determines the context of the `require` function which is the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `module.parent.fileName` and V8 stack trace **works fine**, but it will failed if you export the module in the `index.js`

example:

```
//src/my-lib.js

function myFunction(){
   const path = module.parent.fileName
   //do stuff
}
```

then you export the function above in the `index.js`

```
//src/index.js
const lib = require("./my-lib")

exports.myFunction = lib.myFunction
```

in the client code if you import `myFunction` from `index.js` the `path` detected will always `/src/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use:

```
var path = require('path'); 
//_dirname will give you the current position
```

using path package you can achieve this. [find Documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my question, how do i got the directory of the current executing module using `path` module?

Comment: yeh i misunderstood. may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227489/how-can-one-get-the-file-path-of-the-caller-function-in-node-js